# ArrayList that contains circles that move

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

  ArrayList<Ellipse2D.Double> circles = new ArrayList<Ellipse2D.Double>();
  Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
  double x=0, y=0, velX=1, velY=1;   

  circles.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,10,10));

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(Ellipse2D.Double k : circles){
        g2.draw(k);
    }
    g2.fill(k);
    t.start();
  }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (x < 0 || x > 560) {
    velX = -velX;
  }
  if (y <0 || y >360){
    velY = -velY;
  }
  //x+= velX;
  y += velY;
  repaint();
}
```

I tried doing this but that didnt work I know how to draw them and make them move but I think my problem is initializing the arraylist

error: Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "add", = expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
this error is where i add the circle

Comment: What is the problem? Compilation? Runtime?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Its not obvious from your code!

Comment: what i want is using an arraylist to create circles pretty much and then draw them out

Comment: "circles.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,x,10,10));" should be inside some method

Comment: should i add it in the paintComponent method?

Comment: No, that would add a circle every time you repaint the component.

Comment: Create a new function called `AddCircle` and call it from Main for example.

Comment: how would that method look like?

Comment: It is apparent that you should start with something simpler as you are clearly want to learn the language (or programming in general). Try something without graphical output, just command line output. When you are familiar with that, you can then get on your cirle program again.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute add method only inside another method. 
So you should move this part:

```
circles.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,10,10));
```

to a method.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work.

- If you want the ActionListener to do stuff, you need to add it to a Component like a JButton or so. But I'm guessing maybe you want a MouseListener? (using a mouselistener, you could write a constructor for your class, and add the mouselistener to your window.)
- As 'Jakub Hr' said, you need to write a method, like 'createCircle', where you can add the new circle to your array.

(Also notice that your class-name does not have a Capital. It's probably a type-error.)

Answer (score 0):

```
circles.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,10,10));
```

should be in some method.

Also, method public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) is outside of the class. Check {}